# Dominate vue router with Laravel router

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, vuejs2, vue-router

I am building an application with Laravel and Vue.js. I am using vue router. With this I am controlling all routes. Now, I want to make an url `xyz.com/admin` which will different (Laravel new route, I want to work with this admin separately). I am using this below code, but not working.

```
Route::get(
    '/admin/{view?}',
    "AdminController@index"
);

Route::view('/{any}', 'home')->where('any', '.*');
```

I also remove the admin link from `<router-link>`

```
<v-list-tile-title v-if="isAdminMethod===true">
    <a href="/admin">Admin Panel</a>
</v-list-tile-title>

<v-list-tile-title v-else>
   <router-link :to="{ path: i.to }">
      {{ i.title}}
   </router-link>
</v-list-tile-title>
```

Comment: This kind of thing can be done.  When you it is 'not working', in what manner is it not working (what exactly is happening)?

Answer (score 0):

How about you try something like

```
Route::get(
    '/admin/{view?}',
    "AdminController@index"
);
```

or it might be worth looking into something like [InertiaJS](https://github.com/inertiajs/).

Let me know if you have any further queries.

Comment: It's not working. I have edited my code. Please check.